# Ограничение длинны переменное, либо атрибута name?

Tags: php, html

Добрый день!

У меня есть форма, в ней есть тэг `input` с атрибутом `name="ia-soglasen-poluchat-novostnuiu-rassylku-o-biznes-spravkah-kreditreform"`, после отправки формы, php-скрипт не получает, либо получает пустым это поле.

Скажите, пожалуйста, это ограничение на количество символов в атрибуте `name`, или это ограничение на количество символов в переменной, либо индексе массива POST?

Answer (score 1):

А не быстрее ли будет проверить? ;-)
По результатам приведенного ниже скрипта, проблема ни в том и ни в другом. Экспериментировал для $name длиной 200 символов и его значением также 200 символов. Всё работало корректно. (IIS 5.1 + PHP 5.2.9(ISAPI) ).

Смотрите внимательно архитектуру вашего проекта. Где-то значение теряете.
Какой фреймворк используете?

```
 <?php
    print_r($_GET);
    $name = 'ia-soglasen-poluchat-novostnuiu-rassylku-o-biznes-spravkah-kreditreform';
    ?>
    <br>
    <form method="get">
    <input type="text" name="<?php echo $name?>" value="<?php echo $_GET[$name]?>" >
    <input type="submit" >
    </form>
```

Comment: Использую CodeIgniter, ограничение в БД 255 символов.

Answer (score 1):

Ограничений на значение индекса ассоциативного массива в PHP нет. Ограничения на размер принимаемых сервером POST-данных задается в директиве `post_max_size` (доступна с PHP 4.0.3), и по умолчанию составляет 8 Мб.

Что касается Вашего случая - я так понимаю, input имеет тип "`checkbox`"? Такой input отправляется на сервер только при условии `checked == true`. Если `checked == false` то в POST-массиве просто не будет этой переменной, а если `checked == true` и не установлено значение `value`, то переменная в POST-массиве будет иметь пустое значение.

Comment: ДА верно, но есть ещё одно поле, оно уже type=text name=ukazhite-adres-dostavki-spravki-adres-elektronnoi-pochty-ili-nomer-faksa
Оно так же не проходит. Обрабатывает всё это дело CodeIgniter, там вообще весь массив POST циклом проходит, и вот только вот эти последние две поля не обрабатываются. Хм, может быть MySQL виновата, хотя врятли.

Comment: Скорее виноват CodeIgniter - чужой фреймворк = чужая логика. Либо убедитесь, что поля являются частью формы... ;)